My text input do not show with query in my code
I am trying to get the current location of the marker in my code. Now everything works fine once I dont add the query,but I need to query in order to search places in my placeholder. Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, Alert, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { FontAwesome5, MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { useNavigation, } from "@react-navigation/native";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { Avatar } from "react-native-elements";
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import styles from "./styles";
import PlaceRow from "./PlaceRow";
import { CustomMapStyle } from './CustomMapStyle';

const GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'I Have my key here';

const DestinationSearchPage = ({ route }) => {
  const [originPlace, setOriginPlace] = useState(null);
  const [destinationPlace, setDestinationPlace] = useState(null);
  const [region, setRegion] = useState(null);
  const [destinations, setDestinations] = useState([]);
  const [pinPosition, setPinPosition] = useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        Alert.alert('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      const { latitude, longitude } = location.coords;
      setRegion({
        latitude,
        longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0062,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0061,
      });

      fetchLocationDetails(latitude, longitude); // Fetch and set the location details
    })();
  }, []);

  const fetchLocationDetails = async (latitude, longitude) => {
    try {
      const geocodeResponse = await axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`);
      let address = geocodeResponse.data.results[0] ? geocodeResponse.data.results[0].formatted_address : 'Address not found';

      setInputValue(address); // Update the inputValue state with the address

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching location details', error);
    }
  };

  const handleDestinationInputChange = (text) => {
    setInputValue(text);
    // Additional logic for handling destination input change if needed
  };

  const onRegionChangeComplete = (newRegion) => {
    setRegion(newRegion);
    const { latitude, longitude } = newRegion;
    setPinPosition({ latitude, longitude });
    fetchLocationDetails(latitude, longitude); // Fetch and set the location details
  };

  const saveLastSearchedLocation = async (location) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("lastSearchedLocation", location);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving last searched location", error);
    }
  };

  const checkNavigation = () => {
    if (originPlace && destinationPlace && destinations) {
      navigation.navigate('SearchResults', {
        originPlace,
        destinationPlace,
        destinations
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkNavigation();
  }, [originPlace, destinationPlace, destinations]);

  const { lastSearchedLocation } = route.params || {};

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
        <View style={styles.DestContainer} height={'100%'} backgroundColor={'#112b4d'}>
          <MapView
            style={{ height: 150,  }}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            showsMyLocationButton={true}
            showsPointsOfInterest={true}
            rotateEnabled={false}
            showsBuildings={true}
            showsCompass={true}
            customMapStyle={CustomMapStyle}
            followsUserLocation={true}
            currentLocation={true}
            showsTraffic={true}
            loadingEnabled={true}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            enablePoweredByContainer={false}
            initialRegion={region}
            animate={true}
            onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChangeComplete}
          >
            {pinPosition && (
              <Marker
                coordinate={pinPosition}
                title="Your Location"
              >
                <MaterialIcons name='person-pin-circle' size={30} color='black' />
              </Marker>
            )}
          </MapView>

          <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder='From'
            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
              setOriginPlace({ data, details });
            }}
            textInputProps={{
              value: inputValue,
              onChangeText: handleDestinationInputChange,
              onFocus: () => setInputValue(''), // Clear the input when focused
              onBlur: () => setInputValue(prevValue => prevValue || inputValue), // Set to previous value or 'From' when blurred
            }}
            enablePoweredByContainer={false}
            suppressDefaultStyles
            returnKeyType={'search'}
            fetchDetails={true}
            minLength={2}
            styles={{
              textInput: styles.textInput,
              container: {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 250,
                left: 45,
                right: 52,
              },
              listView: {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 105,
              },
              separator: styles.separator
            }}
            query={{
              key: GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
              language: 'en',
              components: 'country:TT',
            }}
            renderRow={(data) => <PlaceRow data={data} />}
            renderDescription={(data) => data.description || data.vicinity}
          />

I tried writing three different functions but nothing worked, all had the same results.

Any help is greatly appreciated
